# Unexpected Results with doxygen option “TEMPLATE_RELATIONS”: not affecting Class Hierarchy Tree page using C#

Tags: c#, generics, doxygen, hierarchy

(using Doxygen V 1.8.16)
The description for this option is “If the TEMPLATE_RELATIONS tag is set to YES then the inheritance and collaboration graphs will show the relations between templates and their instances.”

But I can’t get this to work on the class hierarchy page.  It consistently shows the specific Type variants of a Generic class outside of any kind of tree structure, at the same “level” as the Generic definition itself.

[image]

I’m trying to make it so that variants, that implement a particular type for a generic class, appear to be “derived” from, or rather, ”based” upon the generic class.
It actually seems to work great when I go to the class page for the GenericClass, where looks perfect:

[image]

**Main Question:**  How can I make the graphical (and ideally, textual) class hierarchy page(s) show the relations like the version shown on the class's page?

Here is the code used for the simple example I tested this with:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A Generic Class.. variants usually defined inline as a member of another class
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">type passed to the generic class upon declaration</typeparam>
    public class GenericClass<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// the member of type T held by the generic class
        /// </summary>
        public T member;

        /// <summary>
        /// nothing special
        /// </summary>
        public int aNonGenericMember;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds a couple of variants of GenericClass
    /// </summary>
    public class HolderOfGenericClassVariants
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// string variant of GenericClass
        /// </summary>
        public GenericClass<string> stringVariant;

        /// <summary>
        /// float Variant of GenericClass
        /// </summary>
        public GenericClass<float> floatVariant;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds a couple of variants of GenericClass, derived to ensure heirarchy shows in docs
    /// </summary>
    public class DerivedHolder : HolderOfGenericClassVariants
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// int Variant of GenericClass
        /// </summary>
        public GenericClass<int> intVariant;
    }
}
```

I should mention: I also tried adding the following to the code file, specifically for doxygen to use:

```
//! \class GenericClass<string>
//! \extends GenericClass\<T>
//! \brief Concrete variant of Generic class
```

But this leads to BOTH versions (mine and the one in code) showing up on the hierarchy page, which is perhaps, even more confusing:
[image]

Comment: You mention doxygen version 1.8.6, it this correct as this is a version from December 2013, the current version is 1.8.16. Furthermore please also add the names of the pages where you see the images (like html/inherits.html, for easy referencing and discussion). Please also mention all the flags different from the default Doxyfile (since 1.8.15 this is easy to obtain with `doxygen -x`).

Comment: Looks that you are using 1.8.16. When you think it is a bug please fie an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: Err.. my bad.. missed the "1" when typing the Q.  version is indeed 1.8.16.. will edit Q now.  Regarding other flags.. I started with the default doxy file, and changed it to use java/c# parsing, and set that one TEMPLATE_RELATIONS flag mentioned in the Q.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug, or I just missed something ELSE in the config..  what do you think?

Comment: Doesn't look like to me that you missed something in the configuration.

Comment: created issue: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7281